# Javascript/CSS, How to keep changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I have this header that slides out of the way when people don't want it anymore and can be slid down again when they want it. I want it to be down by default however I don't want people to have to constantly click the header toggle every-time a new page loads. I have read about using cookies but my skill in javascript is rather limited. Here is the code I currently use that works well:

```
<div id="headtoggle" onclick="headertoggle()"></div>
<script>
        function headertoggle() {
            var top;
            var pagetop;
            if (document.getElementById("page-header").style.top === "-210px") {
                top = "-11px";
                pagetop = "275px";
            } else {
                top = "-210px";
                pagetop = "80px";
            }
            document.getElementById("page-header").style.top = top;
            document.getElementById("page-body").style.top = pagetop;
        }
</script>
```

How do I change the code so that it "remembers" what the last setting was for each person? I am willing to also use jquery. Any help for this very novice coder would be more than appreciated.

Thanks,
Dylan

---

**EDIT2**: I changed the code given to me a bit and am having a new problem.

```
 <div id="headtoggle" onclick="headertoggle()" onload="topposition()"></div>
<script>
    function topposition() {
        var top;
        var pagetop;
        if (localStorage.getItem("headerDown") == "false") {
            top = "-11px";
            pagetop = "275px";
        } else {
            top = "-210px";
            pagetop = "80px";
        }
        document.getElementById("page-header").style.top = top;
        document.getElementById("page-body").style.top = pagetop;
    }
</script>
<script>
    function headertoggle() {
        var top;
        var pagetop;
        if (document.getElementById("page-header").style.top === "-210px") {
            localStorage.setItem("headerDown", false);
            top = "-11px";
            pagetop = "275px";
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("headerDown", true);
            top = "-210px";
            pagetop = "80px";
        }
        document.getElementById("page-header").style.top = top;
        document.getElementById("page-body").style.top = pagetop;
    }
</script>
```

The toggle works as intended however whenever I fire "function topposition ()" in the firefox console I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script data:,/*
>   EXPRESSION EVALUATED USING THE FIREBUG COMMAND LINE:
>   */%0A%09function%20topposition() Line 2

Comment: headertoggle is invoked onclick so if you want it to be down by default you might want to create another function that keeps it down when your page loads.

Comment: You should look into cookies more. Here are a couple resources: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/cookies.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a cookie by using

```
document.cookie="headerDown=true";
```

Then when the header is moved up overwrite the cookie with the same code changed to false.

If you then add some code that reads the cookies on page load you will be able to determine what is need.

You can read cookies by accessing document.cookie which will be a string of any cookies available in the following format.

```
cookie1=value; cookie2=value; cookie3=value;
```

Look for your cookie and you should be able to set whether the header is up or down from there.

Comment: As I stated above I have read up on cookies (on w3schools). Unfortunately my knowledge of javascript is so that that information flies over my head. How would I integrate that into the above code?

Comment: Ended up getting the cookie solution to work. thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

i would say local storage would be a good option for this. Just log an event or variable or whatever and then check for it each time you load the page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.localStorage

Answer (score 1):

Using local storage will allow you to save variables between page loads.
add localStorage.setItem(name,value) in to your if statements as below.
If you are only using the headerToggle function to position these elements then the if statement below the function should suffice. It requires two calls to the headertoggle function in the even that you want the header to be down.

You will need to make sure the if statement is placed after the html for the divs, most likely best place is the very bottom of the page.

```js
function headertoggle() {
  var top;
  var pagetop;
  if (document.getElementById("page-header").style.top === "-210px") {
    localStorage.setItem("headerDown", true);
    top = "-11px";
    pagetop = "275px";
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("headerDown", false);
    top = "-210px";
    pagetop = "80px";
  }
  document.getElementById("page-header").style.top = top;
  document.getElementById("page-body").style.top = pagetop;
}

if (localStorage.getItem("headerDown") == "true") {
  headertoggle();
}
headertoggle();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your assistance. I have tried placing in the code as in the first post (EDIT2)... however I am getting a problematic error.

Comment: What's the error? Which approach did you take? cookies or local storage

Comment: I edited my original post.... please see "EDIT2" in the original post along with everything that follows it